# is this optional keyword redundant?

Tags: asn.1

```
KDC-REQ ::= SEQUENCE {
        -- NOTE: first tag is [1], not [0]
        pvno [1] INTEGER (5) ,
        msg-type [2] INTEGER (10 -- AS -- | 12 -- TGS --),
        padata [3] SEQUENCE OF PA-DATA OPTIONAL
            -- NOTE: not empty --,
        req-body [4] KDC-REQ-BODY
}
```

I thought everything in square brackets was optional so why does `padata` have the word `OPTIONAL` explicitly as part of its definition?

Comment: I suggest that you read the ITU-T Recommendation X.680 for ASN.1 specification of basic notation. Single square brackets are used for tag definition. Double square brackets are - in later ASN.1 syntax - used for version specifications.

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets in your ASN.1 snippet are for specifying ASN.1 tags, not for indicating optionality.  Your question leads me to believe you could use a couple of references for more information.

An excellent introduction to ASN.1 can be found at http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/asn1-made-simple/introduction.html along with a couple of books available as free downloads from http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/books-whitepapers-pubs/asn1-books.html.